# Will using delete with a base class pointer cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Given two classes have only primitive data type and no custom destructor/deallocator.
Does C++ spec guarantee it will deallocate with correct size?

```
struct A { int foo; };
struct B: public A { int bar[100000]; };
A *a = (A*)new B;
delete a;
```

I want to know do I need to write an empty `virtual` dtor?

I have tried g++ and vc++2008 and they won't cause a leak. But I would like to know what is correct in C++ standard.

Comment: I had most serious bug in my life when I mixed inheritance with no virtual methods with memory pool. Just don't do that, it is not safe.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unless the base class destructor is virtual, it's undefined behaviour. See 5.3.5/4:

> If the static type of the operand [of the delete operator] is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand's dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: That is located in [n3242](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) at 5.3.5/**3**.  None of the answers explain what happens if you have a virtual destructor.  Are we only worried about the destructor here?  Destructor aside, will the actual subclass be "removed" from memory?  If so, then subclasses that don't need destructors wouldn't leak.

Comment: @Nathan: if the base class has a virtual destructor everything works. Otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

When's there's a virtual destructor, all the destructors are called (each derived class down the chain has a virtual destructor, even if it isn't declared virtual or isn't explicitly defined at all) and the memory is cleared up.

Answer (score 16):

According to the C++ standard, what you have is undefined behaviour - this may manifest itself as a leak, it may not, For your code to be correct you need a virtual destructor.

Also, you do not need that (A*) cast. Whenever you find yourself using a C-style cast in C++, you can be fairly sure that either it is unecessary, or your code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behaviour - maybe everything's fine, maybe whetever goes wrong. Either don't do it or supply the base class with a virtual destructor.

In most implementations this will not leak - there're no heap-allocated member functions in the class, so the only thing needed when `delete` is done is to deallocate memory. Deallocating memory uses only the address of the object, nothing more, the heap does all the rest.

Comment: May I ask how *the heap does all the rest*? In my understanding, we need virtual destructor to provide information about the object on the heap ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11745527/16500459))

Answer (score 0):

It will deallocate with correct size, because the size to be deallocated is a property of the heap memory region you obtained (there is no size passed to `free()`-like functions!).

However, no d'tor is called. If 'B' defines a destructor or contains any members with a non-trivial destructor they will not be called, causing a potential memory leak. This is not the case in your code sample, however.

Comment: Where do you see a "free-like function" ? One of the reasons C++ uses a `delete` __operator__ instead of a function is a direct compiler implementation. The compiler _does_ know `sizeof(A)`, and it also knows that A has no virtual destructor, so it is allowed call `FourBytePool::free(void* p)` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

For only primitive data I believe you're fine. You might legitimately not want to incur the cost of a v-table in this case.
Otherwise, a virtual d'tor is definitely preferred.

Comment: −1. The spec says, it's UB, see other answers. When you free a `Derived` object thru a `Base*`, you do something virtual, ergo you pay for it. There's no way around it (unfortunately).