# Why if I delete the pointer to the base class I have a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, polymorphism

I have the `base` class and the class that inherits the `base` class:

```
class base
{
};

class derived : public base
{ 
    std::string str;
};
```

I need to manage a `derived` class using the pointer to the `base` class, but the following code causes a memory leak:

```
base* ptr = new derived();
delete ptr;
```

Have I to cast `ptr`, or there are better alternatives?

Comment: add virtual destructor in base class

Comment: Virtual destructor, Dude! ;)  Great link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/07/127826.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will using delete with a base class pointer cause a memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100644/will-using-delete-with-a-base-class-pointer-cause-a-memory-leak)

Comment: It actually causes undefined behavior, from the language point of view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a virtual destructor in the base class so the destructor of the derived class is found and called at runtime.  See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/1214731) for more detail.